# jquery and IE submit, ajaxForm not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer-9, submit, ajaxform

I have a form:

```
<form method="post" action="/balda/server.wsgi" id="gameboard" name="gameboard" >
```

with a submit button:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Поиск" style="" onmouseover="CheckElements();">
```

the submit button should send ajax bind process:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#gameboard').submit( function() {
        $.ajax({
            url     : $(this).attr('action'),
            type    : $(this).attr('method'),
            dataType: 'json',
            data    : $(this).serialize(),
            success : function( data ) {
                       onAjaxSuccess( data );
                    }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

There are accepted function:

```
function onAjaxSuccess (result)
```

All this works fine in chrome, ff, opera, safari, but it does not work in Internet Explorer 9 (others not tried it)

In IE9, the result variable is empty.
I tried another bind submit button like this:

```
$('document').ready(function( result )
{
    $('#gameboard').ajaxForm( {    
        type: "POST",
        data    : $(this).serialize(),
        success: onAjaxSuccess,
        dataType: 'json',
        error: function(){ alert ( 'Error loading data format.' ); }
    }); 
});
```

But the result is the same ff chrome safari opera work,  except for IE9  .

Please tell me what could be the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was that IE9 does not understand the format of "JSON" in the encoding cp1251, even though it is clearly stated in the response header. Translation of the JSON response in utf-8 solved the problem with IE9.

Comment: How would i do the Translation of the JSON response in utf-8 ?

Comment: I had the same issue.  Following this advice, I removed `dataType:'json'` and I was able to get the results from the form.

Comment: damn is this still the case? im searching for ways to make this happen but to no avail

Answer (score 2):

make sure there is no space in the type="text/javascript" if there is space in defining type of script then IE wont allows your js to work

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  ....... 
</script>
```

Comment: I said, but "function onAjaxSuccess (result)" is called only result empty. A type like all good. Application is available on the poncy . ru / balda                   Sorry for my english again